# How do I perform this integral? (Feynman Lecture on Physics)

Tags: integration

I was reading through Feynman Lecture on Physics (Volume II) when I encountered this integral:
$$
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:II:8:27}
U=\frac{1}{2}\underset{\substack{\text{all}\\\text{space}}}{\int}
\frac{\rho(1)\rho(2)}{4\pi\epsilon r_{12}}\,dV_1dV_2.
\end{equation}
$$

Two questions about this:

- How do I solve this integral? Both dV1 and dV2 are not independent of each other and they are volumes, so I don't think this is a simple double integral.
- Dr. Feynman then said that the 1/2 factor is necessary because in the integral, we are actually adding up the pairs of charges ($\rho(1)dV_1\cdot\rho(2)dV_2$) twice. What is the intuition for this?

This integral is equation (8.27) in the 8th lecture of volume II:

http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two integration are actually 'independent', since the domain of integration is a cartesian product, i.e. $\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3$. However, I think that the notation is a bit confusing. Probably the following is clearer
$$
U=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3}\frac{\rho_1(x)\rho_2(y)} {4\pi\epsilon |x-y|}d^3x\; d^3y=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R^3}d^3x \;\rho_1(x)\left(\int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{\rho_2(y)} {4\pi\epsilon |x-y|}d^3y\right)
$$
It is infact a double integral (or 6-uple integral, if you prefer).

As for the $1/2$ factor, this has to do with the definition of energy. In fact, *if you agree* with its definition in the case of two point-like charges, which is
$$
U_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{q_1 q_2} {4\pi\epsilon |x-y|},
$$
you will agree with the given expression also in the case of continuous distributions.
Observe that the energy $U_{12}$ of a *system* of two point charges is defined differently with respect to *the energy of the particle $q_1$* in presence of $q_2$  held *fixed*, which is
$$
U_{1}= \frac{q_1 q_2} {4\pi\epsilon |x-y|}
$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy.

Comment: The integral sums up the energy of every particle with respect to every other particle. Since energy corresponds to a *pair*, you're double-counting and need to divide by two?

Comment: I agree. The point is that each energy contribution corresponds to a (non ordered) pair. Making twice a sum (or integral) on any single particle of a pair-symmetric function, give for each unordered pair two times the same contribution.

Comment: Does this mean that the "dV1" and "dV2" in my original question are actually summed up over the same volumes?

Comment: Yes, the are summed up independently over all $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: OK, now I get it! That wikipedia article was also especially helpful. Thank you for your help!